# The index of an item in OrderedMap

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

As the title states, I want to get the index of a particular item. Is there a way to do this?

```
const key = 1
const map = new Immutable.OrderedMap([5, 'a'], [3, 'b'], [1, 'c'])
```

So, in this case, the index of `key` would be `2`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the key sequence from the map:

```
let index = map.keySeq().findIndex(k => k === key);
```

[See the docs for more info.](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/OrderedMap)

Alternatively, you could explicitly iterate over the keys and compare them:

```
function findIndexOfKey(map, key) {
    let index = -1;
    for (let k of map.keys()) {
        index += 1;
        if (k === key) {
            break
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

Comment: That's what I'm doing right now (`.indexOf(key)` to be precise), but I was worried about the performance implications of this method, and wondering if there is a better way

Comment: Well, since OrderedMap doesn't provide a method to get the index itself, you have to find another way. AFAIK sequences are lazy, so it's probably equivalent to a simple loop. Provided an alternative either way.

Answer (score 3):

the best way to do it would be the way immutablejs inners does it.

Like this:

```
const index = orderedMap._map.get(k);
```

https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/blob/master/src/OrderedMap.js#L43

Comment: Problem: When keys are removed from a map, indexes are not updated: `let map = new Immutable.OrderedMap([["a", 1], ["b", 2]]); map.remove("a")._map.get("b") # 1`. Also, it's using non-documented internals, which can be problematic. It's a pity, because that was O(1) instead of O(n) of `findIndex`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the key and value as well as the index, you can iterate over the `entrySeq`

```
orderedMap.entrySeq().forEach((tuple,i) => console.log(`Index ${i} \n Key ${tuple[0]} \n Value ${tuple[1]}`)
```